# Magento: 404 pages showing 200 OK status

Tags: magento

I am using `Magento Enterprise Edition 1.12.0.0` for my online shop.

When I am accessing a 404 url such as `http://www.example.com/badpageurl` then it is showing 404 no-route page with HTTP STATUS as `200 OK`. Whereas it should show it as `404 not found` as HTTP STATUS. Not sure what is worng, because I did no changes in code and configs.

Can anyone please help and let me know how I can fix this issue.

Comment: You need to be clearer. Magento will show you a themed 404 page but to serve that properly you'll get an HTTP 200. What's the actual problem here?

Comment: @Bojangles: No, that's not normal. When Magento shows a 404 page it normally serves that with a HTTP status code 404. This is relevant, namely for search engines.

Comment: My problem is if it shows 404 page then it should show HTTP STATUS as 404 not 200. In other MagentoCE sites I am getting 404 but not in this MagentoEE site, it is giving HTTP STATUS 200 for 404 pages, which is creating SEO issues with Google for my site.